# Parsing Through a 2D Array in PHP Returning Too Many Columns

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a sql table in mysql that looks like this:

```
id     |     name     |     age

1      | Jack         | 17

2      | John         | 18

3      | Luke         | 17

4      | Elise        | 15
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name;";
 $resultStatement = $db->query($query);
 $lines = $resultStatement->fetchAll();

 for($row = 0; $row < count($lines); $row++)
 {
        for($col = 0; $col < count($lines[$row]) /*why does this go up to 5?*/; $col++)
        {
            print $lines[$row][$col] . " ";
        }
        print "<br>";
 }
```

My question is why does this snippet of code

```
count($lines[$row])
```

Go to 5? When I replace that with three my for loops work as intended. Should I give up this approach and go to a foreach loop?

Comment: Probably because the default fetch mode is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, which returns both associative and enumerated array values in `$lines[$row]`... 3 columns each identified by name and by number = 6.... look at the [fetch_style](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) argument

Comment: @MarkBaker I changed `fetchAll()` to `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, which did solve the counting to 6 problem. However this introduced another error in which the $lines array is now no longer accessible (asking for `$lines[0][0]` gives an undefined offset error.

Comment: You're saying to return an associative array, and then trying to access the elements as enumerated.... either request an enumerated array (`PDO::FETCH_NUM`), or access the row elements by their column name ,
 or just use a foreach loop (`foreach($lines[$row] as $value) { print $value . " "; }`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you so much for that last point. Now I should be able to use foreach or the method I had already implement. I really appreciate it!